# Python + Selenium: element not visible

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This is the webpage -- [link](http://hmi.mrud.ir/sabaa/SABAA/Home/Default.aspx?strTownship=0101&g=false). I am going to crawl (In Persian). I have a problem when I am going to click on the next page button. The XPath is:

```
nextpage = '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxSplitter1_CallbackPaneldgd_dgd_DXPagerBottom"]/a[1]/img'
page = driver.find_element_by_xpath(nextpage)
page.click()
```

After the `page.click()` I got the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Some answers say there might be a duplicate XPath, but I could not find such a thing in the source of the webpage.

The complete code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
url = 'http://hmi.mrud.ir/sabaa/SABAA/Home/Default.aspx?strTownship=0101&g=false'
driver.get(url) 
time.sleep(10)   
nextpage = '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxSplitter1_CallbackPaneldgd_dgd_DXPagerBottom"]/a[1]/img'
page = driver.find_element_by_xpath(nextpage)
page.click()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following before clicking on the element:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", page)
```

This is scrolling to the element.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

As per the `Website` if you want to click on the `Next Page Button` you have to induce `WebDriverWait` for the `WebElement` to be clickable following either of the code block as follows :

```
nextpage = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxSplitter1_CallbackPaneldgd_dgd_DXPagerBottom']/a[@class='dxp-lead dxp-button dxp-bi']/img[@class='dxWeb_pPrev_Aqua']"))
nextpage.click()
```

Or

```
nextpage = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxSplitter1_CallbackPaneldgd_dgd_DXPagerBottom']/a[@class='dxp-lead dxp-button dxp-bi']/img[@class='dxWeb_pPrev_Aqua']"))
nextpage.click()
```